# Loops in Shiny html templates

Tags: r, shiny, html-templates

Shiny has html templates with `{{ }}` syntax to embed r code:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{ SHINY_VARIABLE }}</li>
    <li>{{ SHINY_VARIABLE2 }}</li>
</ul>
```

Other web frameworks however can loop over server variables in combination with html.  Basic example from `Django` documentation:

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is very readable with markup in a .html file.  `shiny` can do it like so:

```
library(shiny)

athlete_list <- c('Lebron', 'Serena', 'Michael')

li_vec <- paste0('<li>', athlete_list, '</li>')
li_text <- paste(li_vec, collapse = '')
ul_text <- paste0('<ul>', li_text, '</ul>')

HTML(ul_text)
```

Yuck... It gets uglier as you nest additional elements.  Anyone have a better method?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `stringr::str_glue` on your template.

It's not beautiful but it's slightly more elegant than `paste`, especially when you have to interpolate many variables. Something like:

```html
<ul>
{{ lapply(athlete_list, function(x) { HTML(stringr::str_glue('
  <li>{x}</li>
')) }) }}
</ul>
```

And you can encapsulate it in a function to make it less verbose:

```r
html_loop <- function(items, template = '{item}') {
  lapply(items, function(item) { 
    HTML(stringr::str_glue(template))
  })
}
```

The only caveat to this approach is that you have to always use `item` as the variable name in the loop, so forget about nested loops...

But for simple loops you could even do things like this (it's the use case that led me to search for this in the first place):

#### `app.R`:

```r
# Server side
# ...
file_actions <- list(
  list(
    button = "ls",
    icon = "list",
    heading = "List files",
    command = stringr::str_glue("ls -R {FILE_PATH}")
  ),
  list(
    button = "write",
    icon = "save",
    heading = "Write data to file",
    command = stringr::str_glue("cat {BUFFER_FILE} >> {FILE_PATH}/out")
  ),
  list(
    button = "delete",
    icon = "trash",
    heading = "Remove file",
    command = stringr::str_glue("rm {FILE_PATH}/out")
  )
)
# ...

# UI
# ...
shinyWidgets::panel(
  heading = "File Actions",
  extra = htmlTemplate(
    "templates/components/file-actions.html",
    actions = file_actions
  )
),
# ...
```

#### `templates/components/file-actions.html`:

```html
<ul class="list-group">
{{ html_loop(actions, '
  <li class="list-group-item">
    { 
      actionButton({item$button},
        label = "",
        icon = icon({item$icon}),
        class = "pull-right"
      ) 
    }
    
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
      {item$heading}
    </h4>
    
    <p class="list-group-item-text">
      <code>{item$command}</code>
    </p>
  </li>
') }}
</ul>
```

The syntax highlighting will go out of the window in some editors, but you can still keep the structure close to vanilla HTML while maintaining some readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is closer, still not great...

```
# Function to process looped over html + variable
rHtml <- function(html) {
  html <- paste(html, collapse = '')
  HTML(html)
}

# Server variable
athlete_list <- c('Lebron', 'Serena', 'Michael')
```

Within your html template:

```
<ul>
  {{
  rHtml(sapply(athlete_list, function(x) {paste(
    '<li>', x, '</li>\n'
  )}))
  }}
</ul>
```